# How do check if a record exists in a database using WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have been fishing around for the appropriate direction to go with checking if a login record exists within a database. My intentions are, when the user credentials come in from the login page to use the login name and password and check if it exists using async.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ResultsDTO<LoginDTO>>> PostLogin(LoginFormDTO login)
{
    ResultsDTO<LoginFormDTO> output = new ResultDTO<LoginForFoDTO>();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        output.Success = false;
        output.SetValidations(ModelState);

    }
    LoginFormDTO loginFormDTO = null;
    try
    {
        string encryptedPassword = encryptmystuff(login.pw);
        // validate login
        log logUser = _context.log.SingleOrDefault(m => m.name == login.Username && m.password == encryptedPassword);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: and what sort of problem have you encountered with this code so far?

Comment: P.S. if you're just going to `await` the call to `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` then you might as well just use `SingleOrDefault()` - by awaiting it, you've effectively made it synchronous again

Comment: @ADyson It wont run, but I am trying your solution now.

Comment: "won't run" isn't an error message or problem statement. Please give us  detailed error information. And my suggestion won't resolve your issue, I was just pointing out that using async here was a waste of time unless you're actually going to do something else while the async code is running.

Comment: @ADyson the error is "identifier" missing.

Comment: log loginUser = await _context.log
                    .SingleOrDefault(m => m.name == login.Username && m.password == encryptedPassword);

Comment: you don't need `await` there any more, because the method call is no longer asynchronous. Probably worth you studying more about async / await, by the looks of it

Comment: Regarding the error, can you please show the full error message (and the stack trace if you think it's potentially relevant), and point out the line on which it occurs. And please add that to your question so that everyone will notice it. Thanks.

Comment: I made the update.

Comment: Ok thanks but I'm really a lot more interested in your error. The async thing was just an aside

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'log' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'log' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Portal.API

Comment: and which line is that related to? P.S. I asked you to add these details to the question, not the comments :-)

Comment: @ADyson log logUser =  _context.log.SingleOrDefault(m => m.name == login.Username && m.password == encryptedPassword);

Comment: and it's the same error even after you changed it to what I suggested? Did you get this error _before_ you changed it? Or some other error? It's unclear.

Comment: When I remove await all together, it runs well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change this line

```
log logUser = _context.log.SingleOrDefault(m => 
                      m.name == login.Username && m.password == encryptedPassword);
```

to

```
log logUser = await _context.log.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => 
                      m.name == login.Username && m.password == encryptedPassword);

// return failure if logUser is null
```

This is using `async/await`, which will synchronously execute your code but it will not block a thread while your DB query is getting executed.

On the other hand, if you use `SingleOrDefault()`, then you're blocking a thread during DB operation, which is not a good practice.